# Probability space for stochastic processes

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In Sinai's book on stochastic processes, the definition for discrete time stochastic processes is "a sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in{}T}$ defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)$".

While I think it makes sense that the sequence of random variables may share a commen state space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B})$, I'm wondering why they also share the same probability measure? Aren't the random variables supposed to have different distributions as they move along time?

Can someone help explain where I am mistaken? Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Careful. The distributions of the $X_n$ might be different or not. The distribution of $X_n$ is the probability measure $P\circ X_n^{-1}$. Now this is notationally elegant, but what it says is that for a Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, the distribution tells me how likely the value of $X_n$ lies in $B$. And that is $$P\big(\underbrace{\{\omega\in\Omega:X_n(\omega)\in B\}}_{X_n^{-1}}\big)=P\big(X_n^{-1}(B)\big).$$ So the distributions can be different even though the underlying probability space is the same. If you want to discuss things like whether $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are independent, you have to go further and use their joint distribution.

Answer (score 10):

Michael gave a great answer, and I know this question was asked 3 years ago. However, I spent a long time trying to understand this, and for anybody else confused, I thought I would elaborate a little on Michael's answer:

The main reference is [these notes by Evans](https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~sgalayda/PDFs/Evans_course_notes.pdf). For other helpful references, see [Kozdron's notes](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/revised_lecture1.pdf), [Zitkovic's notes](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/introduction_to_stochastic_processes.pdf), [Gallager's notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap01.pdf), and [the book by Serfozo](https://books.google.com/books?id=JBBRiuxTN0QC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=stochastic+processes+different+probability+spaces&source=bl&ots=jhDoeNEG5Z&sig=0TOaheB8Qs3b5vltQrQH_o8td3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFgQ6AEwB2oVChMIluzLwLGDxwIVR6MeCh3w6Qh9#v=onepage&q=stochastic%20processes%20different%20probability%20spaces&f=false). An important note is that many of these explanations, definitions, and examples are taken directly from the above references. I do not claim to have come up with these myself; I merely assembled the material below from the references above!

In a given $\textit{probability space}$ $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$, a $\textit{random variable}$ maps sample points $\omega \in \Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. There's also another condition on the measurability of the function, but it's usually satisfied, so we don't worry about it here.

It's easiest to think about one dimension $n = 1$. Some examples include: For a coin, $\Omega = \{\mbox{Heads, Tails}\}$. If we were betting and with a payoff structure of $\$ \, 1$ for a head, and $\$ \, 0$ for a tail, the associated random variable would be:
\begin{equation}
X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 \qquad &\mbox{for} \quad \omega = \mbox{heads}, \\
0 &\mbox{for} \quad \omega = \mbox{tails}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

To take another example, consider the sum of the numbers when rolling two die. The sample space is $\Omega = \{36 \, \mbox{pairs possible from} \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \} \}$, and the random variable is:
\begin{equation}
X((n_1, n_2)) = n_1 + n_2,
\end{equation}
where $n_1, n_2$ are the values of the first, second dice rolled, respectively.

Additionally, associated with every random variable is a \textit{probability distribution function}, whch gives the probability that a discrete random variable is equal to some value. In particular, the probability distribution function $f_X : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, 1]$ of a random variable $X$ is defined by:
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = \mathcal{P} \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) = x \}.
\end{equation}
 For probability distribution functions associated with discrete random variables, the name \textit{probability mass function} is used; for continuous random variables, the name \textit{probability density function} is used.

For example, the probability mass function for the coin example is:
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} \qquad &\mbox{if} \quad y = 1, \\
\frac{1}{2} &\mbox{if} \quad y = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The probability mass function for the die example is:
\begin{equation}
f_X(S) = \frac{\min (S - 1, 13 - S)}{36},
\end{equation}
where $S \in \{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 \}$.

For spinner (such as a compass needle) that spins in a random direction, the random variable $X$ takes values in $[0, 360)$. The probability density of $X$ is $\frac{1}{360}$. While the probability of getting any chosen number is $0$, the probability of getting a number in any open interval is nonzero. This can be calculated by multiplying the (Lebesgue) measure of the set by $\frac{1}{360}$. For instance, choosing the set to be $[0, 90]$, we find the probability to be $(90 - 0) \times \frac{1}{360} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Let $\mathcal{T} \subset [0, \infty)$. A $\textbf{stochastic process}$ is a family of random variables $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathcal{T}}$, indexed by $\mathcal{T}$, defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$.

If $\mathcal{T} = \mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathcal{T} = \mathbb{N}_0$), we call $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathcal{T}}$ a $\textbf{discrete-time process}$. For $\mathcal{T} = [0, \infty)$, we call $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathcal{T}}$ a $\textbf{continuous-time process}$.

For example, if $\mathcal{T}$ is a singleton set, like $\mathcal{T} = \{ 1 \}$, then $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathcal{T}} = X_1$ is just a single random variable.

We are now ready to tackle the distinction between the probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ and the probability distribution $f_X$ of a random variable $X$. The key is that $\mathcal{P} : \mathcal{F} \to [0, 1]$, and does not vary in time. However, $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (in other words, $\Omega$ maps sample points to $\mathbb{R}^n$, while $\mathcal{P}$ maps measurable sets to $[0, 1]$) and thus $f_X : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, 1]$.

Keeping track of the domain and ranges of these functions helps one figure out what $\mathcal{P}, f_X$ are.

We now consider an example.

Recognizing that although we usually identify $t$ as time, mathematically it serves as a placeholder, so we can associate it with very different random variables. In the simplest case, we take $\mathcal{T}$ to be a singleton set $\{ 1 \}$, so $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathcal{T}} = X_1$ is just a random variable.

Using the example from Wikipedia, we consider this discrete-time stochastic process and consider a group of people $G$. Let the random variable $X$ map each person to his or her height (i.e. $\in \mathbb{R}$). The probability density function (notice that although it is a discrete-time process, the random variable, height, is continuous) $f_X$ needs to be integrated to find the probability:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}[a \leq X \leq b] = \int_a^b \, f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d} x.
\end{equation}

Here, the key is that $\mathcal{P}$, the probability measure, gives the probability of any (measurable) set, but the distribution $f_X$, when graphed, plots the values of the random variable; namely, the heights (x-axis) and the probability density of people in the group $G$ having that height (y-axis).

To see this for a continuous-time stochastic process, we use the example from Kozdron's notes:

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$, and let $Z$ be a random variable with ($\mathcal{P}(Z = 1)$ means $\mathcal{P}\{\omega \in \Omega \mid Z(\omega) = 1\}$) $\mathcal{P} (Z = 1) = \mathcal{P} (Z = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Define the continuous time stochastic process $X = \{ X_t, t \geq 0 \}$ by:
\begin{equation}
X_t(\omega) = Z(\omega) \sin t \qquad \mbox{for all} \quad t \geq 0.
\end{equation}

If we fix $t$, $X(t, \cdot) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is the random variable $X_t$ which has the following distribution:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}(X_t = \sin t) = \mathcal{P}(X_t = - \sin t) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}

If we fix $\omega$, $X(\cdot, \omega) : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ describes a sample path of $X$ at $\omega$. In this case, there are two possible trajectories, each occurring with probability $\frac{1}{2}$:

Case 1: $Z(\omega) = 1$ The trajectory is $t \to \sin t$.

Case 2: $Z(\omega) = -1$ The trajectory is $t \to - \sin t$.

Notice how $\mathcal{P}$ is fixed, since we are still in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$.

Namely, we see that random variables have different probability functions (also called probability distributions) as time progresses if and only if the random variables that characterize the stochastic process are time-dependent.

Comment: THANK YOU!  Your explanation here is exactly what I was looking for.  The examples are especially helpful.